# JQuery: переназначение событий

Tags: jquery, javascript

В JQuery не силен совсем.. есть пара вопросов..

1. как назначить реакцию элемента(div) на onclick.. точней так.. есть меню на div'ах, надо чтоб при нажатии на любой из них вызывалась функция..
2. как в jquery получить data-* из дивов по которым нажали..

Comment: http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#grovelling

Comment: ну вот сразу так грубо...) я не преуменьшаю свои знания js, а лиш констатирую факт их отсутствия, что удалось нагуглить - нагуглил и сделал, то что нагуглить не удалось - спросил тут) но данный язык мне нужен раз в сто лет, и к сожалению его изучение займет времени больше чем принесет пользы.

Comment: собсно любой из примеров допиливать под себя придется, т.к. я не привел вам код формы, а лиш задал вопрос в некой сферичности от иерархии и названия форм, что исключает просьбу готового решения..)

Comment: @ToRcH565 этот пункт не столько про "сделайте за меня" а сколько про предоставление бессмысленной информации.

> Не тратьте свое время, и наше, уповая на жалость. Представьте лучше факты и свой вопрос как можно яснее. Так вы заявите о себе гораздо лучше, чем путем самоунижения.

> а лиш задал вопрос в некой сферичности от иерархии и названия форм

а так вообще лучше не делать

Comment: вообще, если вам кажется, что я поступаю грубо, просто прочитайте тот документ от начала до конца и ваши вопросы будут находить ответы гораздо быстрее и точнее чем когда-либо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ```
   $('.wrapper').on('click', function() {
       /* Тут обрабатываем событие */
   });
   ```
2. Если получить как атрибут, то:

   ```
   $(selector).attr('data-*');
   ```

Comment: по второму пункту - лучше так не делать, если data не была задана через .data() то оно считает атрибут, но если была, то заданное значение, причем jQuery data позволяет хранить как текст так и объекты.

Comment: Судя по вопросу автора, он имел в виду именно этот вариант.

Comment: именно тут уже плюсик от меня есть) и пора бы принять его)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы на вашем месте все-же прочитал документацию

1. `$(parent).on('click',selector,handler)` //где handler - функция обработчика параметром которой является объект Event а контекстом тот элемент на который кликнули.
2. ```
   $(element).data('name');
   ```

Пример

```
$('.menu').on('click','.menu-item',function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var $this=$(this);
   $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
 $($this.data('article')).addClass('active')
   .siblings().removeClass('active');
})
```

Comment: а за наталкивание куда копать спасибо) в любом случае расходится с тем что успел почитать о html5 и jquery))

Comment: И в чем же расхождение ?
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3mD5X/

Comment: видел такие примеры, $(this).data('name'), но ваш коментарий под другим ответом и тест - показали не работоспособность такого варианта.)

Comment: как же они показали интересно ? вы мой пример вообще видели ? там вовсю используется именно этот метод.